# .NET IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens how to validate token?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-identity, identitymodel

I am using the IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens package to create my JsonWebToken.

This is the code that creates the token:

```
        public string CreateToken(User user)
    {
        byte[] secret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration.JwtKey);
        SymmetricSecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secret);

        Dictionary<string, object> claims = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            [ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier] = user.Id,
            [ClaimTypes.Name] = user.Username,
            [ClaimTypes.Email] = user.Email
        };

        SecurityTokenDescriptor descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Claims = claims,
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
        };

        JsonWebTokenHandler handler = new JsonWebTokenHandler();
        handler.SetDefaultTimesOnTokenCreation = false;
        string token = handler.CreateToken(descriptor);
        return token;
    }
```

This is the code that I used in my previous application using the AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer package:

The token creation:

```
        public string CreateToken(User user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.Name),
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value!));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            signingCredentials: credentials
        );

        var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        return jwt;
    }
```

And this is my code in the Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)
        ),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});
```

How can I update this code so it uses the IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens package ?

Comment: To switch your token validation from AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer to IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens, install the IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens package. In Program.cs, update the token validation parameters to use a SymmetricSecurityKey from your configuration and clear the existing security token validators before adding the JsonWebTokenHandler for validation. You can mostly keep the token creation code using JsonWebTokenHandler, with the option to create a JwtSecurityToken directly for more control